# How to put custom emoji in embed footer | Discord.py

Tags: python, discord.py

I have tried putting my custom emoji as a footer like this:

```
embed.set_footer(text=f"<:Bloxxer:793683622238224384> Bloxxer")
```

It does not work and comes out exactly as in the string in the footer. Is it possible to set a custom emoji in a footer in discord.py?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think discord.py allows for putting emojis in the footer of an embed but if you would like to put one in a field see the below code.

```
@client.command()
async def embed(ctx):
    emoji = client.get_emoji(id=EMOJI ID)
    embed = discord.Embed()
    channel = ctx.message.channel.id
    embed.add_field(name='emoji', value=f"{emoji} Bloxxer")
    await ctx.send(embed = embed)
```

Comment: I get the error message has no attribute server. I also tried this:

Comment: emoji = get(ctx.guild.emojis, name="Bloxxer")

Comment: And it just still gives me the id

Comment: The emoji is in the server I am testing this on btw

Comment: please see my updated post @PythonProgrammer

Comment: I just get None after putting the emoji in. It's ok thoough because I figured out how to put image in footer which is actally what I meant to do. https://i.ibb.co/Pt2sCJ5/image-2020-12-30-204708.png

Comment: If it returns none it is because the emoji doesn't exist. You would need to place `793683622238224384` instead of where it says `EMOJI ID`

Comment: I did but it did not work. That is what I orginially did too

Answer (score 0):

You can use the emojis that are in The Unicode Standard (such as ✅ or ). You won't be able to use emojis from servers but. If you're on Windows you can open a list of emojis that are in The Unicode Standard type **Windows logo key + period**.

Comment: Yeah, what I meant by emoji was a footer picture but I was inexperienced back then but I soon figured out how to do it like 1 month after I posted the question. Thanks anyways though.